# "Я отдыхал, блуждая по лесу(,) наслаждаясь природой" - деепричастие к деепричастию?

Tags: грамматика, деепричастия

**Я отдыхал, блуждая по лесу(,) наслаждаясь природой.**

Здесь, предположим, мне важно подчеркнуть, что *наслаждаясь* связано с *блуждая*, а не напрямую с *отдыхал*. Перестроить фразу можно элементарно, но в академических целях интересно именно такое её построение.

Я не знаю, как назвать эту предлагаемую к рассмотрению конструкцию и есть вообще ли что-то подобное в русском языке, но если есть, то как организовать пунктуацию.

Повторюсь, предложения изменить фразу на варианты типа "Я отдыхал, блуждая по лесу в поисках наслаждения природой", как и на любые другие, меня сейчас не интересуют. Интересно сохранить два деепричастия - причем так, чтобы второе относилось к первому, а не к основному глаголу.

(+)
По наущению комментирующих (shampar) ввожу в рассмотрение еще один вариант

*Я отдыхал, наслаждаясь природой(,) блуждая по лесу*

Фраза на слух совсем не выглядит дикой.
Это отдельным пунктом, поскольку не совсем равно изначальному. Тут, как верно
пишет автор, оба деепричастия "оторвались" от глагола. А заодно, как мне кажется, и друг от друга. А я исходно имел ввиду строгую двухуровневую иерархию. Но тоже любопытный случай - с точки зрения синтаксиса.

(++)
Еще фраза, чтобы было понятно, о чем я вообще.

*Он неловко повернулся, задев при этом стул.* - безупречно с точки зрения грамматики, не правда ли?!
Теперь делаем из всей этой конструкции большой деепричастный оборот (а кто запретит?), превращая "повернулся" в деепричастие.

***Он попрощался, неловко повернувшись(,) задев при этом стул.***

Ну ясно же, что по смыслу не "попрощался, задев", а именно так, "повернувшись(,) задев". Но тут грамматика вроде бы дает сбой. 
Вот как такую фразу передать, если это вообще возможно?!

(+++)
Вообще начинаю подозревать, что подобная иерархия в русском языке возможна только в трех случаях: многоуровневое ССП (тут понятно), пресловутый "многородительный" падеж (муж сестры жены брата племянника соседа) и нанизанный инфинитив (думали решить послать сходить купить выпить). В остальных случаях, все куда более жестко.

Comment: Хороший вопрос! Ждём первый ответ, в котором предложат перестроить предложение, а потом второй, в котором скажут то же самое.Я тут не советчик, но деепричастие по определению примыкает к глаголу "классически". Однако речь живая, есть же всякие неполные формы и прочие, неподдающиеся строгим правилам предложения. Я бы запятую поставил. Деепричастие к деепричастию. Почему нет? В ремарках пьес деепричастия к существительным пишут. И ничего.

Comment: «Я отдыхал, наслаждаясь природой блуждая по лесу.» ==== Второе здесь стало первым и от этого оба отскочили от глагола, как мне кажется. Запятая (опустил намеренно) нужна, но она фразу портит.

Comment: shampar Интересно, хотя и не совсем то, что я имел в виду. Дополню вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

```
   Интересно сохранить два деепричастия - причем так, чтобы второе относилось 
   к первому, а не к основному глаголу.
```

Такие конструкции возможны, вот у Розенталя: *Но Клим видел, что Лида, слушая рассказы отца поджав губы, не верит им (М. Г.)*. Запятой нет между двумя деепричастными оборотами, потому что второй оборот тесно примыкает к первому, является смысловым центром: Лида слушала поджав губы, это не два действия, второй деепричастный оборот называет процессуальный признак добавочного действия, лишённый глагольности, его можно заменить сочетанием "с поджатыми губами".

Однако это никак не относится к Вашему примеру: *Я отдыхал, блуждая по лесу, наслаждаясь природой.*

Нельзя перестроить фразу без изменения смысла: "блуждая с наслаждением". Если бы было одиночное деепричастие, это было бы возможно, хотя и с натяжкой. Я вижу здесь именно два действия, хотя они и оба дополнительные, семантика предложения: *Я отдыхал в то время, когда блуждал по лесу и наслаждался природой*. Получается, это всё-таки два однородных деепричастных оборота и запятая между ними необходима по общим основаниям.

Однажды мы подобный пример рассматривали, там тоже возможна  "двухуровневая иерархия": *Весёлый датский сказочник встретил меня на пороге нового века, рассматривая меня внимательно прищурив один глаз и посмеиваясь.* Вот здесь возможно не ставить запятую, однако у автора стоит, значит, он воспринимает как однородные обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами и одиночным деепричастием. Сказочник рассматривал ( как?), внимательно прищурив один глаз и посмеиваясь. Может быть, из-за распространённости оборота, если б было "прищурившись и посмеиваясь", может, и не поставил бы.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо. Только єто все не совсем то. Здесь нет иерархии. Деепричастия во всех вашим примерах прежде всего относится к глаголу, а не не к другому деепричастию. Вот поэтому  я и подбирал такой пример, чтобы деепричастие относилось именно к другому деепричастию. И не было бы одиночным, то есть явным образом обстоятельством образа действия. Я попробую еще более убедительный пример сгенерировать.

Comment: Деепричастный оборот в любом случае обстоятельство образа действия (как?).Запятой не будет только в том случае, если второй оборот не будет собственно деепричастным, если он потеряет глагольное значение и превратится в именной оборот с наречным значением, а если будут два действия подряд, хотя и дополнительных, они всё равно будут однородными и будут разделяться запятыми.