# Я работаю(,) лежа в кресле, задрав ноги(,) и представляю себе систему координат, нарисованную на потолке

Tags: деепричастия

Я как-то задавал вопрос о деепричастии, относящемся к другому деепричастию - ["Я отдыхал, блуждая по лесу(,) наслаждаясь природой" - деепричастие к деепричастию?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460244)

Столкнулся с реальным примером еще более сложного (для меня) случая.

***Я работаю(,) лежа в кресле, задрав ноги(,) и  представляю себе систему координат, нарисованную на потолке.***
Тут первое деепричастие "лежа [в кресле]", хотя и не является одиночным, явным образом претендует на роль обстоятельства, неразрывно связанного со сказуемым, то есть обособление, как понимаю, не является обязательным - это как минимум.

Но что тогда делать со вторым - "задрав ноги"?!

Answer (score 2):

Доброе утро, весеннее утро!  Приятно видеть вас на форуме.

К сожалению, **я вряд ли могу ответить на этот вопрос**, но, может быть, вам будет интересно  почему.

**Чтобы ответить, мне надо знать про этого работающего человека всё.** И про весь текст тоже. Также мне нужно понять  то, что называют коммуникативностью: кому это написано, с какой целью, что его адресату известно об авторе. Может быть, это записки для себя или просто размышления вслух?

К примеру, я должна понять эту пару сказуемых – **работаю и представляю**. Между ними действительно однородные отношения? Но я бы скорее предположила бы, что персонаж наш работает в удобной для него творческой позе, представляя себе систему координат на потолке, как на листе бумаги.  Но тогда это выглядело бы так:

***Что я сейчас дЕлаю? Я рабОтаю, лежа в кресле, задрав ноги,  — представляю себе систему координат, нарисованную на потолке.***

Таким образом,  с помощью слов и знаков нам нужно **нарисовать эту картинку**.  Поза в этом варианте перенесена **на второй план** (то есть ряд обстоятельств обособлен), так как ударение падает на сказуемое.  Связь между сказуемыми я обозначаю тире, считая ее **пояснительно-присоединительной**, но не однородной.

Вариант без обособления также возможен (однородные обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами), но там другой контекст:

***А теперь пора за работу. Выглядит это примерно так. Я работаю лежа в крЕсле, задрав нОги  — представляю себе систему координат, нарисованную на потолке.*** Теперь поза подчеркнута, ряд не обособляется.

Но это только варианты…

Не знаю,  как вы отнесетесь к такому неформальному подходу.  Мне хотелось бы, чтобы не правила задавали нам оформление текста, а **чтобы мы пользовались правилами так, как нам удобно** с точки зрения семантики и художественного изображения действительности.

Comment: Sharon, все гораздо проще. Весь контекст укладывается в одну фразу. *"Не надо говорить мне, что ось Y направлена вверх. Я работаю лежа в кресле, задрав ноги, и представляю систему координат, нарисованную на потолке"*.  Сказанное - небольшая переделка фразы известного математика Дж. Литлвуда, которой он иронизировал над авторами, навязывающими свое представление об математических объектах с помощью бытовых терминов.

Comment: Да, забавно. Но всё-таки в чем-то я права: без контекста оформить предложение сложно. А в этой редакции знаки расставлены верно. Ряд обстоятельств не обособляется, так как логически выделена поза, а запятая перед союзом И присоединительная.  Изображены, как мне представляется, две ситуации, которые надо соотнести между собой, поэтому пауза между ними  нужна. Там даже тире вместо запятой (перед И) можно поставить для выразительности.

Comment: Sharon, вы, видимо, упустили из виду, что вопрос не о том, правильно ли поставлены знаки, ибо из четырех возможных вариантов расстановки обсуждаемых запятых - как минимум три допустимы. Вопрос в общем-то о том, как лучше передать на письме ту необычную (и, вероятно, даже некодифицированную) ситуацию, когда одно деепричастие (задрав) относится прежде всего к другому (лежа), что исключает идею об однородности оных, а к глаголу - только опосредованно через это последнее, что ставит под сомнение и вариант неоднородности ряда. Одни как бы иерархичны...

Comment: (продолжение) На другом ресурсе предложили трактовать подчиненный оборот ("задрав ноги") как уточняющий, с чем я отчасти согласен, но не до конца. По тем же причинам - непонятно, как можно одним деепричастием уточнять другое.

Comment: Одно деепричастие  (задрав) относится прежде всего к другому (лежа)?   А почему? Ведь эта чистая грамматика, а какой она имеет смысл? Нельзя, к примеру, написать: лежа в кресле и при этом задрав ноги. Или как-то еще выразить тот смысл и те отношения между деепричастиями, которые вы хотите выразить.

Comment: *А почему?* - по смыслу. Вы модете себе представить, работу в позе "задрав ноги"? Я - нет. Без "лежа" смыл какой-то идиотский получается. Не знаю, "чистая" ли это грамматика, или еще какая, но это решительно ничего не объясняет. Ну и то, что для обозрения потолка надо задрать голову, а не ноги.